# Online Shopping - Social Feedback on Clothing - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, us20130132240, online-shopping

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON Online shopping for clothes with input from your friends** - This application seeks to patent the idea of...Getting feedback from your friends on clothes and outfit while you shop online! 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 11/18/2011** that discusses:

> - Social feedback on clothes or outfits while shopping online

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - A reference to anything that meets all of the criteria to the question above AND ALSO involves a **virtual mannequin**.

**TITLE: Online shopping for clothes with feedback from your friends**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] First user shopping for clothes online.  Second user presented same item. First user picks the item as part of an outfit.  Second user provides a comment which is presented to both first and second users

- **Publication Number**: [US 20130132240 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/US20130132240)
- **Application Number**: US 13/300,421
- **Assignee**:
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 11/18/2011
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 11/19/2013

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A method for online shopping in an online shopping system, the method comprising:
>
> 1. providing a first user interface identifying an item of apparel for presentation to a first user;
> 2. providing a second user interface identifying the item of apparel for presentation to a second user;
> 3. receiving from the first user an indication to associate the item of apparel with an outfit;
> 4. receiving from the second user a comment regarding at least one of the outfit and the item of apparel; and interfaces such that the comment and outfit are viewable by the first user and the second user.
> 5. providing the comment and the outfit for presentation in the first and second user

In English this means:

> A method for shopping online for clothes, comprising:
>
> 1. First and second users are shown an item of apparel (e.g. sneakers)
> 2. First user associates the item of apparel with an outfit (e.g. a tuxedo)
> 3. Second user comments on the item and the outfit ("hey, those sneakers look great with that blue tuxedo!")
> 4. Comment is provided to first and second user.

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 11/18/2011

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming displaying the clothes on a **virtual mannequin**

---

**"Online shopping with integrated social experience from the Applicant"**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Comment: Would prior art for this include people using Facebook, Twitter, etc. to ask their friends about potential online purchases?  Or does it need to be integrated into the storefront to be prior art?

Comment: Jon, The cleanest prior art would be citeable-evidence, e.g. a publication such as a link to a PDF online, a URL on [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org) from a company which did this in the past or an article about a company which did this in the past, or another patent (or patent application) which describes some or all of these steps. Hypothetical users doing this on Facebook starts to look more like an obviousness argument, which is difficult to get through the AIA pre-grant submission process.  See [this answer](http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/a/167/1767) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

[This article from January 2011](http://mashable.com/2011/01/10/fashion-advice-sites/) lists "4 Online Platforms for Personalized Style Advice" each of which do this to some extent.

But even more importantly, I think [Apple patented this in 2009](http://www.google.com/patents/US20100191770), no?